# .htaccess: Check if query string has a certain value or else redirect it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to learn a bit of .htaccess and am really anxious on what it can do. I saw a snippet online but can't get it to work, it basically goes like this **If a query string does not have a certain value, redirect it to index.php** instead or some other page. How do I do that?

This looks for the value *apples*:

```
www.domain.com/somefile.php?a=apples&b=xyz
```

This will redirect to index.php instead:

```
www.domain.com/somefile.php?a=stinkycheese&b=xyz
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the %{QUERY_STRING} variable inside a RewriteCond. So for example, if you don't want to redirect if there exists a `redirect=no` in the query string, it would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)redirect=no($|&)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So if the RewriteCond fails (it has a `redirect=no` in the query string), then do not apply the following rule, which rewrites whatever the request URI is to `/index.php`. The actual rule that you need may be different, but using RewriteCond and %{QUERY_STRING} is the basic idea that you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, that really helped a lot. Since .htaccess can scan queries using QUERY STRING can it also delete it parts of it? For example, it strips out redirect=no after doing the checking if it exists (or does not exist, depending on usage).

Comment: You can match everything that *isn't* `redirect=no` and use backrefernces (%1, %2, %3, etc) to include it. Something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)redirect=no&?(.*)$` then in your rule: `RewriteRule . /index.php?%1%2 [L]`

Comment: Would you know any worthy web post which talks about using backreferences (%1, %2,%3, etc.)? I'd like to learn more about the sample code you just posted.