# Redirect http to https problems: webpage messy display and back-redirection fail

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have a website whose home page is http://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/appl/index.php As you see, it is based on pmwiki. It is hosted by Apache2.

We want to automatically redirect the login page(bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/appl/index.php?n=Site.Login) from http to https, but keep other pages unchanged.

What I do is to modify /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg
DocumentRoot /var/www/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
/** ignore the following two lines. not related to the redirection **/
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  .*favicon\.ico$         /var/www/favicon.ico [L]

/** Redirect to https only if the query string end with Site.Login **/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pmwiki/farm/appl/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=Site.Login$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/appl/index.php?n=Site.Login [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

With the above code, we manage to redirect the login page. However, the display format for login page is messy. the other problem is when I jump from the login page to other pages, the other pages are redirected to https versions and their displays become messy too. For example, click the Home link at the upper left of the page.

I have no idea for the display problem.

I try to redirect https requests to http for other pages by adding the following code to 
`VirtualHost *:443` section:

```
/** if query_string does not end with Site.Login, redirect it to http**/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^n=Site.Login&
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301]
```

The code does not work. I tried the pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142307/htaccess-check-if-query-string-has-a-certain-value-or-else-redirect-it) , but it does not work either.

Comment: The display issue is because you are attempting to load resources (css files) over http. The secure page would need to load all resources over https. Also chrome doesnt trust your security certificate, but i guess thats because you have just self signed for testing

Comment: I would switch your entire site to `https` for all users on all pages, unless you have a compelling reason to not do so.

Comment: @Steve You are right. I use a self-signed certificate, because the login page is only used by internal users. Any solution to load the resources over https for secure pages? Display is a more serious problem than the other.

Comment: @cmorrissey External users should request over http. The login page is for internal guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `RewriteEngine On` and you don't need to use `QUERY_STRING` explicitly:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if query_string does not end with Site.Login, redirect it to http
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)n=Site\.Login(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

As `%{QUERY_STRING}` is automatically carried over to new URL.

Comment: It still does not work. I suspect something prevents the condition from being recognized.

Comment: See updated rules and place them in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` after enabling .htaccess as that is quicker to test since changing Apache config requires you to bounce it every time.

Comment: You made my day! I forgot to add `RewriteEngine On`. There IS a `On` statement in my code, but it is for SSL. I suggest you emphasize the statement.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the display problem? It is more important for the internal users.

Comment: ok display problem is because your `https://` login page is trying to load css/js files using `http://` e.g. `http://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/pub/wsplus/wsplus.css`. `https` page must have all the resource on `https` including js/css/images.

Comment: The login page contains a lot of `http://`. It is generated by pmwiki's php files. It is hard to change the `http://` links by modifying the php files. Is it possible to write another RewriteRule: if the whole page is requested over `https`, all resources on this page should be loaded via `https`?

Comment: Hmm rewrite rules won't be able to help much other than a weak referral URL based rule. I suggest creating a new question so that you get better answers for this new problem.