# htaccess Mod rewrite rule for redirect /subfolder to /subfolder with query string in the beginning

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

:)

Currently i have a mod rewrite rule in my .htaccess, the rewrite:

announcements.php

to

announcements/

This is the line:

```
RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]
```

Now, in my next step, i want to rewrite this subfolder /announcements to /?ccce=announcements

I tried and adjusted:

```
RewriteRule /?ccce=announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule /?ccce=announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]
```

Unfortunately doesn't work:(

Somebody what is the good rule to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess: Check if query string has a certain value or else redirect it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142307/htaccess-check-if-query-string-has-a-certain-value-or-else-redirect-it)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the article you mentioned is about "if, else" in .htaccess. What i mean is to mod rewrite: www.domain.com/subfolder --> www.domain.com/?ccce=subfolder ... So it's about redirecting /subfolder (and also redirect all folder below these /subfolder.

Comment: The answer is what you are looking for, it shows how to access the query string in htaccess for. **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ccce=announcements($|&)** RewriteRule . /announcements.php [L]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately i got 500 error :(     The first step (announcements.php --> /announcements works with this line:     
  RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]  ....... But when i try to setup   /announcements ---> /?ccce=announcements   it results in 500 error

Comment: Post the code that you tried to get the 500 error

Comment: RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ccce=announcements($|&)
RewriteRule . /announcements.php [L]

Comment: My last comment contains the full line of the code.                                                 
After add the line:                                                                                        
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ccce=announcements($|&) RewriteRule . /announcements.php [L]  i got 500 error

Comment: "the rewrite: announcements.php to announcements/" - Your description is the wrong way round. You are rewriting the request from `announcements/` to `/announcements.php`. But your rules are doing more than this. Is `/announcements` really a "subfolder" (ie. a physical directory) or just a path-segment? If it is a "subfolder" then you will need to take additional steps to prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash. "i want to rewrite this subfolder /announcements to /?ccce=announcements" - this doesn't really make sense given what is written above? Please clarify the source and target URLs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  `/announcements/` is a path-segment (not a physical directory) To clarify my issue:  i have announcements.php ...... I rewrite it to a seo-friendly path segment (`/announcements/`) ..... For that i use this line in .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]` ..... so far everything wents fine.  Now in the next step i want to rewrite the path-segment: `/announcements/` to `/?ccce=announcements/` ..... How to fix this and what to adjust on my rule?